# Removing White Spaces in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, removing-whitespace

Good day. I am currently doing a Server-Client Chat Program using sockets in MFC C++ (in Visual Studio 2010). This is my first C++ program as we were never taught of the said language way back in college (shame)

Anyways, so far I've been doing good. Then, I have added string length which would count how many characters were sent. Thankfully, because of searching the internet and forums, I've made it work. Then here's my problem, the code counts the white spaces and I don't need that. I read about .Trim() but its not what I need. I also did try .Replace() but it's not working. Any other ideas? Here's my code.

> //string length //m_Msg is my message
>
> ```
> CString strCount;
> strCount = m_Msg;
> ```
>
> //strCount = strCount.Replace(" " , "");
>       int Count = strCount.GetLength();

Thanks, thanks for any ideas that may help.

Comment: Yes I was taught FORTRAN-77 at University ;-). If you're only interested in the number of non-white space characters, then the fastest way of doing this would be to count the characters in the string, omitting anything that falls into your definition of whitespace. You ought not to mutate the string in any way (unless, of course you want to use the mutated string) as that will degrade performance.

Comment: The real question is why you are using `CString` instead of `std::string`.  (With `std::string`, you'd have access to such standard functions as `std::count_if` or `std::remove_if`.)

Comment: lucky you. that gave me an idea. 
Need to search again (",)
thanks, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `int CString::Remove( TCHAR ch )` It takes the character you want to remove as argument and returns the number of characters removed.

```
strCount.Remove(' ');
```

Should do what you want. I also agree with the comment saying you should use std::string instead.

Comment: thanks,again and again. I never really know std::string as I have said this is my 1st C++ program and I don't really know what I'm doing. :'(

Comment: CString has a bit simpler interface IMO, std::string may seem complicated, but it's not that bad when you get into it. My suggestion is to look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ it has documentation and examples of most ( all? ) of std::strings functions.

Comment: No problem =)  Please set this answer as the solution if it solved the issue.